# React-router-dom not compiling components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have problem with router-dom. I am working according to youtube tutorial, I cannot resolve below error:
[landingPageLayout] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>. I would be greateful for some guidance.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>  
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import landingPageLayout from './components/layouts/landingPageLayout';
import homePage from './components/pages/homePage';

const App = () => {
  return (
        <Routes>
          <landingPageLayout>
            <Route path="/"> 
              <homePage/>
            </Route>
          </landingPageLayout>
        </Routes>      
  );
}
```

landingPageLayout.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../navigation/header';

const landingPageLayout = ({...otherProps}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default landingPageLayout;
```

Comment: In JSX, custom components need to be capitalized. So `LandingPageLayout`. Lowercase is reserved for the native dom elements, like `div`.

Comment: partially worked, components LandingPageLayout are highlighted that they are in use, npm compiling without errors but when I enter to host page there is still the same Error: [LandingPageLayout] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nicholas said in comments, your react components should always be capitalized.

Other than that, Routes component only accepts  or <React.Fragment> as children so you can't add your layout like that. What you can do is something like this:

```
   const App = () => {
      return (
         <Routes>
            <Route
               path='/*'
               element={
                  <LandingPageLayout>
                     <HomePage />
                  </LandingPageLayout>
               }
            />
         </Routes>      
      );
    }
```

If you have several routes that need this layout, you should replace HomePage with another component that has all the routes. For example we can call it PrivateRoutes. Then in code above you replace `<HomePage />` with `<PrivateRoutes />` and then your PrivateRoutes component should look like this:

```
   const PrivateRoutes = () => {
      return (
         <Routes>
            <Route path="home" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="page1" element={<Page1 /> />
            //rest of routes
         </Routes>
      );
   }
```